# Start a program with a bat file taking administrator privileges without asking with UAC

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm using Windows 10 and I want to start the program called `PhoneMyPC`. When Windows start, that program never start because it needs to approve the action showing UAC window and get Administrator access. I want to start this program on start without asking Administrator access and showing UAC windows. That program has also a service called `PhoneMyPC_Helper`. I'm using the following command at the moment but it doesn't work at all.

**Command:**

```
runas Administrator C:\Users\Malvinarios\Documents\Programs\SoftwareForMe Inc\PhoneMyPC\PhoneMyPC.exe
```

I thought that it might work if I could add the password in that command line but I don't know how. I have also tryied this...

**Command:**

```
start /d "C:\Users\Malvinarios\Documents\Programs\SoftwareForMe Inc\PhoneMyPC" PhoneMyPC.exe
```

Nothing works. Not even showing something when windows start, but it work when I manually run the bat file.

Does anyone has any idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If that was possible the whole idea of UAC would be pointless

Comment: That's true. But is there any other way that I could run this program on start?

Comment: if you are using in 8.1 you can try this: https://code.google.com/p/google-security-research/issues/detail?id=118

Comment: As a standard, typing `yourexecutablename /?` at the prompt *may* show you command-line options. the `/` may be `-` or `--` or even be omitted; `?` may be `h` or `help` depending on the mindset of the designer. Or it may be that this program doesn't provide such information - certainly, there appears to be no mention on the manufacturer's webpage. Perhaps **if** they've implemented this standard method, you may get some clues from the response.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the executable in question using Windows Explorer. Right-click and select Properties. Select the Compatibility tab. Check the "Run this program as an administrator" check box. If you want, you can cause this action system-wide by also clicking the "Change settings for all users" button at the bottom.

If you want to not have to type the password each time, well, you're out of luck there - it's going to UAC prompt each time ... but at least this way you'll not forget to run this program as admin each time.